# Xcode 6.0.1 - Misplaced view errors 'off-by-one', in storyboard when sharing across a team

Tags: xcode, storyboard, autolayout

When opening a shared storyboard in Xcode 6.0.1, I am seeing a number of off-by-one misplaced view errors, mostly in the case of label frames.

For example the error is typically something like: Expected: x=50, y=43 -- Actual: x=49, y=42. Often it's only the y coordinate that needs to be adjusted by one.

Of the four developers on our team, the errors (approx 75 in total) present for only one of the members.

The developer experiencing the issues has re-installed Xcode 6.0.1 removing all supporting files, preferences, and caches in the process. An unmodified version of the storyboard is confirmed and checked out from the source tree, all to no effect.

All dev enviroments are running the latest version of Mavericks (OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)) on MacBook Pros of varying age, but all younger than 3 years.

Anyone else experiencing the same? Any thoughts on what the difference might be? Can an OS level setting or CPU difference influence the calculation of the label view dimensions?

Many thanks,
Alan

Comment: What I see is that I can open a storyboard or xib, fix the misplaced views that have spontaneously appeared, save and close, then reopen and see that they've all returned again. Same basic environment as you but the misplaced views are sometimes off-by-one, sometimes off by a ton.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. No answer to the mystery, but upgrading to Yosemite and Xcode 6.1 seems to have made the warnings/errors disappear. If it's convenient to upgrade, perhaps that will work for you too.

Comment: This is an issue we are currently experiencing @AlanMcEwan. We are all on the latest versions; there are 3 developers on our team. Just a hint: 2 developers have same Macbook configurations (13 inch, same model) while the other developer has a different config. And that developer seems to have different "off-by-one" misplaced views.